# How to change/upgrade users recurring payment agreement?

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I've integrated Paypals recurring payments on a site where they now want to add different 'levels' for the users. Today a user can be a paying member for $10 / month and now my customer wants to add two new levels where the users also could become a Silver-member for $20 / month and a Gold-user for $30 / month. 
Is there any smart solution how to change/upgrade the users recurring payment agreement from $10 to $30 / month? I don't like the idea to hava a solution where the user needs to first quit the ongoing agreement with $10 / month to be start a new for $30 / month.
Any ideas? Thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UpdateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/#id086530108PM) API to modify a recurring payments profile. Among many other things, you can modify the billing amount, tax amount, or shipping amount.

Comment: Ok but I read that I can add maximum of 20% in a fixed 180-day.
This is not lika a price adjustment I'm after. I want the user to easily go to silver or gold membership and to gold it would be going from $10 to $30... Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware there would be a percentage limit. Another option would be to add logic to cancel the existing profile and create a new one when the subscriber upgrades. You can suspend or cancel a profile by using the ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus API.